# Testing data in Ruby Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have an array of arrays in Ruby,

```
array = [["bob", 12000, "broke", "ugly"],
         ["kelly", 50000, "rich", "attractive"]]
```

Each subarray is just a record.  What's syntactically the most elegant construct for testing certain elements of each subarray for certain conditions, such as

- Is the zeroth element in every array a string?
- Is the second element in every array an integer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned every element, the idiomatic way is to use `all?` enumerable. Like this:

```
array = [["bob", 12000, "broke", "ugly"],
         ["kelly", 50000, "rich", "attractive"]]

array.all? { |element| 
  # check whatever you would like to check
  # check if zeroth element is String or not
  element.first.is_a?(String) # this would mean that you are assuming element is a collection, since first generally works on a collection
}
```

[`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: You say `any?` in the first sentence, but the code example uses `all?`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `all?`:

```
all_match = array.all? {|inner_array|
    inner_array[0].kind_of?(String) && inner_array[1].kind_of?(Fixnum)
}
```

Comment: I don't want to delete elements.  I just want to verify the array's integrity before doing stuff with it.